# Как получить длину подстроки с максимальным числом уникальных символов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание, выполнил его частично и застрял. Не могу сообразить как можно организовать выполнение последнего 3-го пункта. Буду очень признателен, если поможете разобраться.

Задание:
Напишите такую функцию counter(T):

1. принимающую на вход кортеж, состоящий из строк латинского алфавита, например, ("ABC", "abc")
2. приводящую строки к единому (верхнему, либо нижнему) регистру определяющую число уникальных символов латинского алфавита для каждой строки
3. (строка "Aaa" содержит всего 1 уникальный символ) возвращает длину строки с максимальным числом уникальных символов (если таких строк несколько, то самой большой из них)

Код программы:

```
def counter(T):
    # читаем строку и приводим к нижнему регистру, разбиваем на строки
    T=str(T)
    T=T[2:-2]
    T=T.lower().split("\', \'")

    length_unic=[]
    length_str=[]
    length_max = 0

    # изменяем число уникальных символов и длину строк, записываем в список
    for word in T:
        length_current = len(word)
        if length_current > length_max:
            length_max = length_current
        length_str.append(length_current)    

        unic = set()
        for letter in word:
            unic.add(letter)
        length_unic.append(len(unic))

    # поиск максимального уникального 
    max=0
    for i in range(len(length_unic)):
        if length_unic[i] > max:
            max = length_unic[i]

    # измерение длины каждой строки
    max_len_unic = length_unic[0] 
    for i in range(1,len(T)):
        if length_unic[i] >= max_len_unic:
            max_len_unic = length_unic[i]

            max_len_str = length_str[0]
            if length_str[i] >= max_len_str:
                max_len_str = length_unic[i]

    #print(length_max)
    print(length_unic)
    print(length_str)

T=('Aa', 'ab', 'AaAa', 'AaAaAa', 'ABBA')
counter(T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, что до конца правильно понял задание, но решение должно быть таким:

```
def counter(T):
    # читаем строку и приводим к нижнему регистру, разбиваем на строки
    T=str(T)
    T=T[2:-2]
    T=T.lower().split("\', \'")

    length_unic=[]
    length_str=[]
    length_max = 0

    # изменяем число уникальных символов и длину строк, записываем в список
    for word in T:
        length_current = len(word)
        if length_current > length_max:
            length_max = length_current
        length_str.append(length_current)    

        unic = set()
        for letter in word:
            unic.add(letter)
        length_unic.append(len(unic))

    # поиск максимального уникального 
    max_uniq=0
    for i in range(len(length_unic)):
        if length_unic[i] > max_uniq:
            max_uniq = length_unic[i]

    # измерение длины каждой строки
    max_len_unic = length_unic[0] 
    for i in range(1,len(T)):
        if length_unic[i] >= max_len_unic:
            max_len_unic = length_unic[i]

            max_len_str = length_str[0]
            if length_str[i] >= max_len_str:
                max_len_str = length_unic[i]

    #print(length_max)
    print(length_unic)
    print(length_str)

    tmp_max = max(length_unic)
    tmp_res = [[index, len(T[index])] for index, value in enumerate(length_unic) if value == tmp_max]
    print(max(tmp_res, key=lambda x:x[1])[1])

T=('Aa', 'ab', 'AaAa', 'AaAaAa', 'ABBAbb')
counter(T)
```

И еще - вы создали переменную `max`, хотя это внутренняя функция, которая находит максимум в массиве. Я переназвал её как `max_uniq`, чтобы всё работало верно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Согласно постановке вопроса задача решается примерно так:

```
def counter(T):
   # это нечто вроде базовой проверки передаваемого функции параметра
   if 'tuple' != type(T).__name__ or \
   1 in list(map(lambda x: 0 in [c.isalpha() for c in x], T)):
      print('Переданные функции данные имеют неверный формат.')
      return
   # находим количество уникальных символов для каждой из строк кортежа
   print(list(map(lambda x: len(set(x.lower())), T)))
   # выводим длину строки с максимальным количеством уникальных символов
   tmp = list(map(lambda x: len(set(x)), T))
   print(len(T[tmp.index(max(tmp))]))
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант решения c вычислительной сложностью `O(n)` (за один проход):

```
def counter(T):
    d = {}
    max_uniq = 0
    max_len = 0
    for i,s in enumerate(T):
        d[s] = {'len': len(s), 'uniq_syms':len(set(s.lower()))}
        if d[s]['uniq_syms'] == max_uniq:
            if d[s]['len'] > max_len:
                max_len = d[s]['len']
        elif d[s]['uniq_syms'] > max_uniq:
            max_uniq = d[s]['uniq_syms']
            max_len = d[s]['len']
    return d, max_len

d, max_len = counter(T)
```

результат:

```
In [27]: max_len
Out[27]: 4

In [28]: d
Out[28]:
{'Aa': {'len': 2, 'uniq_syms': 1},
 'ab': {'len': 2, 'uniq_syms': 2},
 'AaAa': {'len': 4, 'uniq_syms': 1},
 'AaAaAa': {'len': 6, 'uniq_syms': 1},
 'ABBA': {'len': 4, 'uniq_syms': 2}}
```

Comment: Красивое решение, алгоритмически оптимальное) спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

варианты решений покороче:

```
def counter(T):
    return max(map(lambda s: (len(set(s.lower())), len(s)), T))[1]
```

```
def counter(lst):
    un = 0  #переменная для уникальных символов
    n = 0  #переменная для длины строки
    for x in lst:
        t = len(set(x.lower()))
        if t > un:
            un = t
            n = len(x)
        elif t == un:
            n = max(n, len(x))
    return(n)
```